# Raspberry might fail to boot after a power cut, why android does not have problems with this?

Tags: android, failure

As asked in title, can anybody answer? Could raspberry be made equally poweroff resistant as an android phone to which battery is unexpectedly removed?

It would be so great to have a rpi power cut resistant!

Answer (score 3):

Long story short, smartphones and other devices have an internal memory different from SD cards. The technology is supposed to be failure proof. The SD card in another hand is built to be cheap.

If your Android is using the micro SD while you remove the battery, it might corrupt the card as well. Also, the firmware of your phone is stored in a read-only partition in the internal memory.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that one of the raspberry-like boards with nand flash onboard are power cut safe (maybe not 100% safe but equally to an Android phone)?

Comment: Yes. In fact, Beaglebone Black has a internal flash memory which is way more reliable than RPi and SD card. In most of the cases, it's more recommended to use BBB over RPi when your board stays in a hostile environment.